# python 3d array like in C ++

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'd like to make a 3 dimensional array like this one :

```
treedarray = [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

in this table, every value is (easily) accessible by using :

```
treedarray [a] [b] [c]
```

I'd like to know if there is a command to do that more easily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be rather new to Python. Please check out [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). It's a package for numerical stuff, and provides everything you could wish for in a multidimensional array. There's basically no way around it if you want to do numericas in Python. (By the way, you could ger your array using numpy via `treedarray = numpy.zeros((3, 3, 3))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [numpy.zeros()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) you can define the shape with a list of values as the first param. e.g.

```
import numpy as np

treedarray = np.zeros([3,3,3])
print treedarray
```

Outputs:

```
[[[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]
```

And can access the pretended value using, `treedarray[a][b][c]`.